# Slayer Exciter - Upgrade

Tags: tesla-coil

I've built slayer exciter without LED. I was wondering if there is a way how to lighten a bulb without touching the secondary coil first. Also I was interested in how could I "upgrade" this slayer exciter to make it bigger and "stronger" so maybe I could see small lightning,now I  see only sparkling.[image]

Comment: please explain what this means `how to lighten a bulb without touching the secondary coil first`

Comment: sparking is small lightning

Comment: Say I got the bulb near the secondary coil, when I turn the exciter on, the bulb does not light itself , first I have to touch the coil with the bulb and then I can move with the bulb freely around coil and it lights. Hope it is clear a little bit . And how can I make this lightning bigger?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that you made a new account to ask this question ABOUT THE SAME THING... That or people have suddenly become extremely curious about the same device for the last week.

Comment: You are wrong , I have had this account for a few months yet , mainly for programming and math

Comment: VTC. I have no idea what a "slayer exciter" means, or where this "bulb" is connected, if you just removed the LED or made a short instead, or the difference between "lightning" and "sparkling".

Answer (score 3):

Why did you build it without the LED (or any other diode)? That seems to be something a lot of people do for some reason.

It has a purpose in the circuit other than "lighting up" -- it provides the path for the secondary current when the lower terminal tries to go negative. Without it, that current is forced to flow through the resistor and the transistor BE junction (in reverse).

Comment: As I said I am quite new to electronics so I do not know a lot about transistors etc , but how much is the LED necessary? What does BE mean? I thought it is there just to see if the circuit works or not

Comment: BE- base emitter

Comment: @P.Bolfa If you don't know a lot about electronics, you shouldn't be building Tesla coils or Slayer Exciters. Start simple

Comment: What kind of diode would be good here?

Comment: @AgentZebra: It really doesn't matter much. The key point is to provide a path for current when the feedback tries to drive the base negative with respect to the emitter. You could use a 1N4148, or any available LED. It won't see a lot of current and essentially zero reverse bias.