# Slayer exciter 2N3055 to 2N3716, what can explain these behaviours?

Tags: high-voltage, tesla-coil

I built a [slayer exciter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354669/slayer-exciter-upgrade) with a [2N3055](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/68/2n3055-1108522.pdf) from which I can pull 1.5" arcs at ~30V (tried base resistors ranging from 20-30kohm). I was planning to run it at a higher input voltage than the 2N3055 can tolerate, so I was looking for a comparable transistor to swap in. I tried the [2N3716](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/68/2n3713-3716-29197.pdf), but arcs are practically non-existent at 30VDC.

I also noticed on my oscilloscope that the 2N3055 runs at around 530kHz while the 2N3716 runs at around 930kHz for the same circuit and input voltage.

What parameters on those datasheets should I be looking at to explain these discrepancies?

Comment: Was the coil 10:750 turns? Did you use a reverse diode or LED across Vbe?  The LED protects also by creates a bigger ramp and lower frequency, which allows more primary current and thus higher dI/dt.

Comment: It’s not clear what the difference in hFE is with 1 to 1.5 mA base current with a super wide range but could be higher and also the f toggle max rate is almost double 4 vs 2.5MHz at higher current on the 2N3716, but that could increase the frequency which is a combination LC resonance and negative voltage clamp and thus ramp off time.

Comment: UF4007 diode across Vbe. Is a higher ramp why some slayer exciter diagrams have two diodes in series? I have about 1200-1300 on the secondary, 8-11 on the primary, so higher than your ratio. fT is higher on the 3716 for the same voltage and current, but both are running well below that threshold. re:resonance, I thought the point of the slayer exciter is that the oscillation frequency was directly coupled to the resonance of the secondary, so the frequency should always be roughly the same regardless of transistor. This nearly 2x difference seems weird. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: it is most sensitive to output capacitance of 0.1pF Range

Comment: So transistor's base adds capacitance to the secondary's LC circuit, thus increasing the resonance frequency? That could explain the different frequencies. Is there a test to verify that? I've previously added physical nF capacitors to the secondary's base to see what would happen to the resonance frequency, but it didn't seem to change and the trace on my oscilloscope monitoring the transistor's base seemed unaffected. Maybe I'll try that again. Any references analyzing the slayer exciter with more engineering detail? Hard to find good info through the noise since slayer exciter is so popular

Comment: Adding any capacitances anywhere on the input or output ramp reduces f by ^1/2

Comment: Yes the Flyback clamp diode turns off the VBE and up to -7V May be used here giving more time to ramp before turn on

Comment: It would be hard to get an exact model of the transformer from hand wound form. But you can play with Falstad’s to simulate it with 0.1pf to say 100pF on secondary and choose primary L turns  boost ratio and mutual coupling ratio <1 then add diode capacitance, but it’s nonlinearity is not modelled

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm looking at using a zener to regulate the voltage on the base, but it has the same orientation as the UF4007 diode. I'm not clear what interactions this might have at these frequencies; I see some posts suggesting that they could introduce 100s of pF of capacitance. I was thinking I could replace the UF4007 with a series of zeners to achieve an equivalent forward voltage, so the zeners could serve double duty of regulating and pulling the base to ground, but perhaps not. Any thoughts?