# Slayer Exciter circuit not producing electricity

Tags: circuit-analysis, tesla-coil

I used the circuit below to try to make a slayer exciter, but it doesn't seem to be able to power anything around it. Is there anything that I'm missing? Also, yes, I know that in the picture there is no battery :)
[image: My circuit]

Comment: You call this a circuit?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič What else would you call it? Electricity goes through wires. Yes, a circuit.

Comment: A schematic is needed. It shows the intent of your design and what component values you have chosen.

Comment: @Andyaka ok I'll try to make one.

Comment: ooohhh, the original breadboard

Comment: @jstola Ok...? extra characters

Comment: @GabrielWood:  Your circuit seems incomplete. Compare with the circuit [here.](https://chriselison.uk/electronics/2018/02/my-first-slayer-exciter-tesla-coil/)

Comment: @JRE what do you mean incomplete? What part am I missing? I got my instruction from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uwf4rAexbPU) video.

Comment: A slayer exciter normally includes a diode or an LED.  As I understand it, the diode or LED is not optional.

Comment: I was going to say I see no diode

Comment: Where's the LED? They always forget the LED. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354669/slayer-exciter-upgrade

Comment: yeah, it needs the LED, and probably needs a new 2222 also, I see what looks like a PN2222 instead of 2N2222, but it'll probably still work.